# Magento 2.4 How to get the collection of all the UpSells products

Tags: collections, magento2

Want to get all the UpSells products and i dont know if it's possible with a collection or a searchCriteria.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way, it's a custom collection:

```
private function _getUpSells()
{
    // get only the enabled IDs
    $productsIds = $this->_getAllEnabledIds();

    // Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Link as 
    $linkTypeUpSells = LinkModel::LINK_TYPE_UPSELL;
    
    // construct: Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
    $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    $collection->getSelect()
        ->join(
            ['CPL' => 'catalog_product_link'],
            "CPL.linked_product_id = e.entity_id"
        )->where(
            'CPL.link_type_id = ?',
            $linkTypeUpSells
        )->where(
            'CPL.product_id IN(?)',
            $productsIds
        )->group('e.entity_id');

    return $collection;
}
```